# issue counting number of letter occurrences in string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, char

When I input a string that starts with the letter 'a' the program fails to check for that letter and excludes it. If i input a string that has an 'a' just not first in string, it checks out.

Here is the complete problem:

Write a program that will read a line of text and output a list of all the letters that occur in the text together with the number of times each letter occurs in the line. End the line with a period that serves as a sentinel value or delimiting character.

The letters should be listed in the following order: the most frequently occurring letter, the next most frequently occurring letter, and so forth.

Use two arrays, one to hold letters and one to hold integers. You may assume that the input uses all lowercase letters. For example, the input do **be go bo**. Should produce output similar to the following:

Letter Numbers of Occurrence
o 3
b 2
d 1
e 1

Note: you can modify the implementation of the selection sort algorithm in the book to sort the array in descending order. You can use either string type or c-string type in your program.

Code:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;

 void sort(char letters[],int letter_count[])
  {
     for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
      {
        int max = i;
        for(int j=i; j<26; j++)
        {
           if(letter_count[j] > letter_count[max]) max = j;
        }
        int temp = letter_count[i];
        letter_count[i] = letter_count[max];
        letter_count[max] = temp;

         char local = letters[i];
         letters[i] = letters[max];
         letters[max] = letters[i];
         }
  }

 int main()
 { 
   string str;

   char letters[26];
   int letter_count[26] = {0 };
   cout <<"Enter a line of text :";
   getline(cin,str);
   for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
   letter_count[str[i]-'a']++;
   for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
   letters[i] = static_cast<char> ('a'+i);

   sort(letters, letter_count);


   cout <<"Letter Numbers of Occurrence" << endl;
   for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
          if(letter_count[i]!=0)
          cout << letters[i] << "        " << letter_count[i]<<endl;
          }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string starting with 'a' that causes your problem?

Comment: @polb the string that causes my problem is 'apple' for example.

Comment: This may help you hunt for the solution...I'm getting the following results for 'bba': `Enter a line of text :bba
Letter Numbers of Occurrence
b        2
b        1
Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: @AlessandroScarlatti didn't notice that.. I am testing input 'apple' now.. I tested 'do be do bo' and it worked fine.  `Enter a line of text :do be do bo
Letter Numbers of Occurrence
o        3
b        2
d        2
e        1 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found on line 20, where you try to swap `letters[i]` with `letters[max]`. That line should be

```
letters[max] = local;
```

Comment: Thank you! its always the small things you overlook.....